# substitution vocabulary

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, substitution

I am crafting materials for college students in my classes to address algebra misconceptions, and I need a simple set of vocabulary to distinguish between two things when performing complex substitutions:

When substituting one more complex sub-expression in for another equal complex sub-expression in an existing expression or an equation, I want some way to refer to each of these sub-expression using a single word, instead of saying awkward things over and over like "original sub-expression" and "new sub-expression" which are longer and somewhat ill-defined.  I can invent my own vocabulary, but I'm thinking there must be some existing well-defined vocabulary for this in some branch of higher mathematics, or education, or some related field.  I was hoping someone here might be able to help me figure out what terms might make the most sense to use here?

Thanks in advance for reading my post!

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: By *complex* do you men "involving complex numbers" or "complicated"?

Comment: By complex I simply mean complicated.

Comment: For example 5+(2x+3x)+2 = 5+(5x)+2 would be a really simple example of this.